# Overheating with h100i v2

Tags: cooling, overheating, overclocking, intel-core-i5, clockspeed

I'm overclocking the i5-8600k at 4.8ghz 1.37v,
the voltage seems high to what I'm seeing online but its the lowest I can get without Prime95 failing.

Anyway, with the h100iv2 set to performance I'm getting a thermal throttle around 84 degrees.

I've put fresh thermal compound on it, I'm not sure what else to do.

Cooler: Corsair h100i v2

Comment: You get a more effective cooler. If you've eliminated installation issues and bad thermal joints, the remaining option is getting a better cooler. Also, providing us the make and model of the cooler you're currently using would help us understand your question better. Right now this key missing piece means I have no clue what your temps should normally be at that OC.

Comment: the cooler is the h100i v2?

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear that is what that model number refers to.

Comment: If you revert to stock speeds does your system still overheat?

Comment: No, it runs quite cool actually.